# Windows writeFileEx and recvfrom Crashes program

Tags: c, windows, sockets, serial-port

I'm trying to write a very simple C program. For some reason, I can't use writeFileEx and recvfrom within the same program as every call to writeFileEx causes recvfrom to crash.

Here's the relevant code snippet

```
struct sockaddr_in server, client_address;
int client_length, recv_len;
char buf[BUFLEN];
WSADATA wsa;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0 )
{
  //Error
}

SOCKET s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
 //invalid socket error
}

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr= INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

if (bind(s, (stuct sockaddr* ) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  //bind error
}

OVERLAPPED ovWrite;
memset(&ovWrite,0,sizeof(ovWrite));
ovWrite.offset=0;
ovWrite.OffsetHigh=0;
ovWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent (0,TRUE,0,0);

memset(buf,'\0',BUFLEN);


while (1) 
{
  if (!recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN,0,(struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &client_length)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Recvfrom Failed %d\n", WSAGetlastError());
  }

  if (!WriteFileEx(serialHandle, buf, strlen(buf),&ovWrite,NULL))
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to COM port %d\n", GetlastError());
  }
   memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
}
```

I am using lcc compiler, and the resulting program crashes on the second iteration of the loop with Access Violation 0xc0000005. 
When I replace recvfrom with another input source such as stdin, the program runs fine.
Is this a known issue or the 2 function calls simply cannot exist together?

Comment: 'Is this a known issue or the 2 function calls simply cannot exist together?' - neither.  Your code has bugs.

Comment: Why is the address of the completion routine NULL?

Comment: I have made it as minimalist as possible to eliminate any bugs, but still crashes. Can you identify a bug in the above snippet?

Comment: It is null because at present I do not intend to do anything upon completion of WriteFileEx - just keep listening for more data.

Comment: Please indicate where buf and ovWrite are declared an allocated - overlapped I/O calls MUST use a different OVL block, and nearly always a different buffer, for each call.  Usually, I put the buffer and OVL struct as members of a class, instantiate one with new, load the hEvent parameter of the OVL with the 'this' pointer and then issue the call.  In the completion routine, the instance can be retrieved easily by casting the hEvent back again.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in MSDN that indicates that WriteFileEx() will not try to call NULL and so AV.

Comment: ..also, what ingo says.

Comment: Even upon adding a completion routine, the program still crashes

Comment: Are you allocating a new buffer and OVL block each time round, (and deleting them in the completion routine)?  WriteFileEx is asynchronous and the buffer+OVL MUST exist until the completion routine is *called back later*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will modify relevant portions of the code. However, if I replace recvfrom with ,say, gets(buf), it runs as expected. Any idea as to what could be causing the conflict between recv and writefileEx?

Comment: There is no conflict outside your code :)  gets is slower, so prob. allows your code to just about work-ish.

Comment: Also, what is overall thread structure?  Where are you waiting in an alertable state?

Comment: Maybe you should just use WriteFile, ie. synchronous.

Comment: I have 2 threads: a readThread and a writeThread, so Overlapped IO works best for me. I have tried writeThread on its own but same error occurred.  I also inserted sleep(5000) but the same crash still occurred, so I do not think it is a speed issue.

Comment: Thanks Martin, you were right. I think calling NULL must have been the issue. After creating a callback with the right number of arguments, it runs fine and as expected.

Comment: 'char buf[BUFLEN];', 'OVERLAPPED ovWrite;' - as I suspected, you are using the same buffer and OVL for, quite possibly, multiple async. overlapped I/O calls.  This will not work.  You MUST use a different buffer and OVL for EACH invocation of WriteFileEx.  Define a 'IOstruct' that contains both, new/malloc up a pointer to a IOstruct thisIO* instance of the struct, put the pointer in OVL.hEvent, (yes - inside itself), and issue the WriteFileEx with a pointer to the contained OVL, ie &thisIO->OVL

Answer (score 0):

`recvfrom()` doesn't add a `'\0'` to `buf`, so at least() if `recvfrom()` reads `BUFLEN` bytes, or at the first call, if `buf` isn't initialized outside your code snipplet, calling `strlen()` causes UB. Besides, your `if( recvfrom( ... ) )` is wrong, becaus in case of success, `recvfrom() returns the number of bytes received, so the condition would be true. Instead you can do it like that:

```
size_t received;

....

if ((received = recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN,0,(struct sockaddr *) &client_addres, &client_length)) <= 0 )
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Recvfrom Failed %d\n", WSAGetlastError());
}

if (!WriteFileEx(serialHandle, buf, received,&ovWrite,NULL))
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to COM port %d\n", GetlastError());
}
```

Comment: IIRC, WriteFileEx() requires a valid completion routine pointer, not NULL.

Comment: @Martin James: I've just googled: the last parameter `lpOverlapped` may be `NULL` if the file was not opened with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`

Comment: @Martin James forget the last comment please, i didn't look correctly :-(

Comment: @user2667394: that's wrong too: in case of errors() `recvfrom()` returns -1 wich would be interpreted as 'true'

Comment: Thanks Ingo. Lemme make changes.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt You are confusing with WSARecv etc, I know :)

Comment: I think I have sorted it out. Calling NULL in WriteFileEx must have been the culprit. After creating a CallBack function with proper arguments, the program no longer crashes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll promote myself to delivering an answer:)  Some points:

1) Unlike WASRecv, say, WriteFileEx() always requires a valid completion routine to callback the completion of an asynchronous write call.  Other signaling mechanisms, like using hEvent synchro, are not available for this call.  Passing NULL is likely to result in an AV.

2) In general, UDP messages can be any length 0..64K.  recvFrom() returns the actual length of such a message and this value should be used to handle it - not any BUFFER_LEN or strlen() call, (see Ingo answer:).

3) The IP stack can handle concurrently a blocking read from one thread and a write from another - it's not strictly necessary to resort to asynchronous, overlapped I/O.

4) If you are going to use overlapped I/O, it is highly recommended to use a different OVL block and buffer for each call - in general, multiple overlapped operations can be queued up at the same time and they must each have their own buffer/OVL.  I use a malloced struct, (or, if C++, new class instance), or a *struct allocated from a pool, for each call to ensure this.  The struct/instance can be feed/deleted/repooled in the completion routine after handling, (or queued off the thread and handled/freed/deleted/repooled later, somewhere else).

5) A thread that wishes to perform overlapped I/O with completion routines should look like a loop around one of the alertable wait calls.  WaitForSingleObjectEx() is convenient since it can wait on a semaphore that forms the basis of a producer-consumer queue in an alertable manner, allowing other threads to signal commands/buffers/whatever into the thread performing the overlapped I/O.